# How to analyse an iOS 8.2 Messages misbehaviour?

Tags: iphone, ios, sms

### Bug description

In iOS 8.2 I just discovered a misbehaviour of `Messages` application
within the function to delete SMS.

When a given discussion is opened, I want to select and delete a set of SMS. To achieve this I usually long-tap on one SMS to make the `Copy | More…` menu appear, and choose `More…`. Then the current SMS is automatically selected and the bottom changes to a menu with a blue trash on the left and a blue arrow on the right.

Actually this function is unreachable. When I long-tap on one SMS the hidden `Copy | More…` menu appears:

[image: iOS 8.2 Messages 1]

but the bottom does not change. The function to delete a message or a set of messages is not there:

[image: iOS 8.2 Messages 2]

I compared the `Messages` settings with one running iOS 7.1.2 wich doesn't present this problem. They have exactly the same configuration.

### Workaround for the dummies

If I quit the `Messages` application, the bug vanishes…
temporarily.

### Question

Is this a known problem?

Might this be a configuration error I made and which I didn't see?

Might this be a bug?

How may I diagnose this for sure?

Comment: Top menu is changing correctly, just not the bottom… I'd do the usual suspects… force-quit app; reboot; iTunes sync/backup/restore - which may insist on updating to 8.3, not certain on that. If you look carefully at the 2nd image, the bottom part of the screen has a double line, the first [correct] image doesn't. Looks like a screen refresh bug of some sort. [Late thought] do you have any non-Apple keyboards?

Comment: Eagle's eye :)! I didn't notice the double line.↵I agree with your fast amnalysis: this looks like a refresh pb.. But moreover I would like to understand first.↵I don't have any non-Apple keyboard.

Comment: I'd be tempted to call "glitch" but as I know of no way to poke around in the machinations of an iPhone to test how/why, I'd just plod through the varying degrees of 'reset'

Comment: (Side note: backup/restore will force an update to 8.3, yes, since Apple has stopped signing 8.2.)

Comment: → tubedogg: thank you for the improvment with the *long-tap* neologism I ignored :).

Comment: @tubedogg - thanks for the confirmation. I don't have any devices not on 8.3 so no way to even test. @ danielAzuelos - let us know how it goes :)